# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'results' not found. 'results' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django

```
Views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from . models import Question
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    latest_questions = Question.objects.all()[:5]
    context = {'latest_questions': latest_questions}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})


def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except():
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question, 'error_message' : "Please select a choice"})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

I get this no reverse match for results dues it not being a valid view function. I am new to django. How can I solve this?Does it mean there's an issue with my view.py code or what could be the issue as I am following a tutorial.

```
polls/urls.py
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

    urlpatterns=[
        url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),

        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-2]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-2]+)/results', views.results, name='result'),

        url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-2]+)/votes', views.vote, name='vote'),
    ]
```

This is the polls/templates/polls/results.html file

```
Results.html
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}

{% block main_content %}

<h1>{{question.question_text}}</h1>

<ul>
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <li> {{choice.choice_text}} -- {{choice.votes}} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote Again?</a>

{% endblock %}
```

This mysite/urls.py where I used namespace there. What could be the issue.

```
 Mysite/urls.py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf.urls import url, include

    urlpatterns = [

        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^polls/', include(('polls.urls', 'polls'), namespace='polls')),

    ]
```

Comment: Your URL pattern is named "result", not "results".

Answer (score 4):

You have used `reverse` in the view: `vote`. Change the first argument from "*polls:results*" to "*polls:result*" or "*result*".

`Reverse` is used to point to a URL pattern defined in `urls.py`. Look at the third entry in your urlpatterns, you have provided name "*result*" to it.
That should solve your problem.